# Property 'register' does not exist on type 'NestExpressApplication'

Tags: nestjs

According to [nestjs documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/helmet) I want to use `fastify-helmet`  in order to config `contentSecurityPolicy`.
first I installed the following package:

```
$ npm i --save fastify-helmet
```

in my **main.ts** I registered `fastifyHelmet` but it throw the following error :

> Property 'register' does not exist on type 'NestExpressApplication'

```
async function bootstrap() {
    const logger = new Logger('bootstrap') 
    const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);
  
    await app.register(fastifyHelmet); // this line thorw error
    ...
    
    const PORT = process.env.PORT
    await app.listen(PORT);
    logger.log(`Application is start on port : ${PORT}`)
  }
  
  bootstrap();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to register a `fastify` package to your `express` based app which does not work.

There are 2 possibilities to fix your issue:

1. Use a express compatible package (for example helmet: `npm i --save helmet)` and then register it with: `app.use(helmet)` (express does not use .register but .use)
2. Change your NestJS App to Fastify: (`npm i --save @nestjs/platform-fastify`) and then: `const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(AppModule, new FastifyAdapter());` -> then the fastify-helmet package (and .register) should work!

More details about using fastify instead of express are available at the official documentation page: [NestJS Documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/performance)